# Retrieve images from Google Places API

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using the Google Places api to get places data:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json? + "location=" + strlatitude + "," + strlongitude + "&" +"radius=" + searchRadius + "&" +"types="+ types + "&" + "sensor=true" + "&" + "key=" + googleAPIKey;
```

I am just getting only "icon" from this response.But I want to get image of that place.

Is there any parameter to get the image of the places?

Additionally, how can I get reviews of the places (like 9reviews, 6reviews, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `image_link` by using `JSONObject`, and you can easily convert the particular link to an image using `Bitmap`.

**For example, getting `image_link` from `Json`:**

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(Global.JSON.toString()); 

// Creating JSON Parser instance
JSONArray jr=jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

for(int h=0;h<jr.length();h++)
{       
    JSONObject js=jr.getJSONObject(h);      
    icon_array=js.getString("icon");    
}
```

***Converting Link to Image***

```
url = new URL("http://www.paho.org/Images/DD/PIN/whd08_banner2_eng.jpg");
//In URL pass your link

bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
image_view.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: I am getting "icon" but how can I able to get image of particular place

Comment: @David,can you please answer the question?

Comment: I dont know about location image.Google providing only the icon_image in their Json..

Comment: Its ok and what about reviews concept

Answer (score 0):

I found the link to get the location image from places Api..

**try this link**

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,%20-73.988354&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&sensor=false

***you'll get image like this for the above link***
[image]

***Refernce Link***
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/